# Selenium 2.46.0 org.openqa.selenium.firefox.NotConnectedException: Unable to connect to host 127.0.0.1 on port 7055 after 45000 ms.

Tags: selenium, firefox

I am getting the following exception while trying to run Selenium 2.46.0 with Firefox 52 on my MAC by just instantiation a new instance of FirefoxDriver

```
org.openqa.selenium.firefox.NotConnectedException: Unable to connect to host 127.0.0.1 on port 7055 after 45000 ms. Firefox console output:
features/deployment-checker@mozilla.org.xpi
1492032549324   addons.xpi  DEBUG   Loading bootstrap scope from /Applications/Firefox.app/Contents/Resources/browser/features/deployment-checker@mozilla.org.xpi
1492032549330   addons.xpi  DEBUG   Calling bootstrap method startup on deployment-checker@mozilla.org version 1.0
1492032549330   addons.xpi  DEBUG   Registering manifest for /Applications/Firefox.app/Contents/Resources/browser/features/e10srollout@mozilla.org.xpi
1492032549330   addons.xpi  DEBUG   Loading bootstrap scope from /Applications/Firefox.app/Contents/Resources/browser/features/e10srollout@mozilla.org.xpi
1492032549331   addons.xpi  DEBUG   Calling bootstrap method startup on e10srollout@mozilla.org version 1.9
1492032549332   addons.xpi  DEBUG   Registering manifest for /Applications/Firefox.app/Contents/Resources/browser/features/firefox@getpocket.com.xpi
1492032549333   addons.xpi  DEBUG   Loading bootstrap scope from /Applications/Firefox.app/Contents/Resources/browser/features/firefox@getpocket.com.xpi
1492032549336   addons.xpi  DEBUG   Calling bootstrap method startup on firefox@getpocket.com version 1.0.5
1492032549342   addons.xpi-utils    DEBUG   Starting async load of XPI database /var/folders/ww/gv287wh16h1dc2_vfkbqhzzsljzc90/T/anonymous2050536623730480419webdriver-profile/extensions.json
1492032549343   addons.xpi  DEBUG   Registering manifest for /Applications/Firefox.app/Contents/Resources/browser/features/webcompat@mozilla.org.xpi
1492032549343   addons.xpi  DEBUG   Loading bootstrap scope from /Applications/Firefox.app/Contents/Resources/browser/features/webcompat@mozilla.org.xpi
1492032549344   addons.xpi  DEBUG   Calling bootstrap method startup on webcompat@mozilla.org version 1.0
1492032549347   addons.manager  DEBUG   Registering shutdown blocker for XPIProvider
1492032549347   addons.manager  DEBUG   Provider finished startup: XPIProvider
1492032549347   addons.manager  DEBUG   Starting provider: LightweightThemeManager
1492032549347   addons.manager  DEBUG   Registering shutdown blocker for LightweightThemeManager
1492032549347   addons.manager  DEBUG   Provider finished startup: LightweightThemeManager
1492032549347   addons.manager  DEBUG   Starting provider: GMPProvider
1492032549355   addons.manager  DEBUG   Registering shutdown blocker for GMPProvider
1492032549356   addons.manager  DEBUG   Provider finished startup: GMPProvider
1492032549356   addons.manager  DEBUG   Starting provider: PluginProvider
1492032549356   addons.manager  DEBUG   Registering shutdown blocker for PluginProvider
1492032549356   addons.manager  DEBUG   Provider finished startup: PluginProvider
1492032549357   addons.manager  DEBUG   Completed startup sequence
1492032549818   addons.xpi-utils    DEBUG   Async JSON file read took 0 MS
1492032549818   addons.xpi-utils    DEBUG   Finished async read of XPI database, parsing...
1492032549822   addons.xpi-utils    DEBUG   Successfully read XPI database
1492032549843   addons.manager  DEBUG   Starting provider: <unnamed-provider>
1492032549843   addons.manager  DEBUG   Registering shutdown blocker for <unnamed-provider>
1492032549844   addons.manager  DEBUG   Provider finished startup: <unnamed-provider>
*** Blocklist::_loadBlocklistFromFile: blocklist is disabled
1492032549976   addons.manager  DEBUG   Starting provider: PreviousExperimentProvider
1492032549976   addons.manager  DEBUG   Registering shutdown blocker for PreviousExperimentProvider
1492032549977   addons.manager  DEBUG   Provider finished startup: PreviousExperimentProvider
2017-04-12 14:29:11.058 plugin-container[31127:15159940] *** CFMessagePort: bootstrap_register(): failed 1100 (0x44c) 'Permission denied', port = 0x933f, name = 'com.apple.tsm.portname'
See /usr/include/servers/bootstrap_defs.h for the error codes.
2017-04-12 14:29:11.060 plugin-container[31127:15159940] *** CFMessagePort: bootstrap_register(): failed 1100 (0x44c) 'Permission denied', port = 0x4f17, name = 'com.apple.CFPasteboardClient'
See /usr/include/servers/bootstrap_defs.h for the error codes.
2017-04-12 14:29:11.060 plugin-container[31127:15159940] void __CFPasteboardSetup() : Failed to allocate communication port for com.apple.CFPasteboardClient; this is likely due to sandbox restrictions

    at org.openqa.selenium.firefox.internal.NewProfileExtensionConnection.start(NewProfileExtensionConnection.java:118)
    at org.openqa.selenium.firefox.FirefoxDriver.startClient(FirefoxDriver.java:246)
    at org.openqa.selenium.remote.RemoteWebDriver.<init>(RemoteWebDriver.java:119)
    at org.openqa.selenium.firefox.FirefoxDriver.<init>(FirefoxDriver.java:191)
    at org.openqa.selenium.firefox.FirefoxDriver.<init>(FirefoxDriver.java:186)
    at org.openqa.selenium.firefox.FirefoxDriver.<init>(FirefoxDriver.java:182)
    at org.openqa.selenium.firefox.FirefoxDriver.<init>(FirefoxDriver.java:99)
    at com.cobaltgroup.websites.kpi.BaseKPILeads$KpiWebDriverFactory.createLocalWebDriver(BaseKPILeads.java:156)
    at com.cobaltgroup.websites.kpi.BaseKPILeads.setup(BaseKPILeads.java:91)
    at com.cobaltgroup.websites.kpi.kia.KiaLeadSubmissionTest.setUp(KiaLeadSubmissionTest.java:57)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:57)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:606)
    at org.junit.runners.model.FrameworkMethod$1.runReflectiveCall(FrameworkMethod.java:47)
    at org.junit.internal.runners.model.ReflectiveCallable.run(ReflectiveCallable.java:12)
    at org.junit.runners.model.FrameworkMethod.invokeExplosively(FrameworkMethod.java:44)
    at org.junit.internal.runners.statements.RunBefores.evaluate(RunBefores.java:24)
    at org.junit.rules.TestWatcher$1.evaluate(TestWatcher.java:55)
    at org.junit.rules.TestWatcher$1.evaluate(TestWatcher.java:55)
    at org.junit.rules.RunRules.evaluate(RunRules.java:20)
    at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner.runLeaf(ParentRunner.java:271)
    at org.junit.runners.BlockJUnit4ClassRunner.runChild(BlockJUnit4ClassRunner.java:70)
    at com.saucelabs.junit.ConcurrentParameterized$SauceClassRunnerForParameters.access$300(ConcurrentParameterized.java:170)
    at com.saucelabs.junit.ConcurrentParameterized$SauceClassRunnerForParameters$2.run(ConcurrentParameterized.java:287)
    at com.saucelabs.junit.ConcurrentParameterized$NonBlockingAsynchronousRunner$1.call(ConcurrentParameterized.java:312)
    at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:262)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1145)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:615)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:745)

org.openqa.selenium.WebDriverException: Failed to connect to binary FirefoxBinary(/Applications/Firefox.app/Contents/MacOS/firefox-bin) on port 7055; process output follows: 
features/deployment-checker@mozilla.org.xpi
1492032549324   addons.xpi  DEBUG   Loading bootstrap scope from /Applications/Firefox.app/Contents/Resources/browser/features/deployment-checker@mozilla.org.xpi
1492032549330   addons.xpi  DEBUG   Calling bootstrap method startup on deployment-checker@mozilla.org version 1.0
1492032549330   addons.xpi  DEBUG   Registering manifest for /Applications/Firefox.app/Contents/Resources/browser/features/e10srollout@mozilla.org.xpi
1492032549330   addons.xpi  DEBUG   Loading bootstrap scope from /Applications/Firefox.app/Contents/Resources/browser/features/e10srollout@mozilla.org.xpi
1492032549331   addons.xpi  DEBUG   Calling bootstrap method startup on e10srollout@mozilla.org version 1.9
1492032549332   addons.xpi  DEBUG   Registering manifest for /Applications/Firefox.app/Contents/Resources/browser/features/firefox@getpocket.com.xpi
1492032549333   addons.xpi  DEBUG   Loading bootstrap scope from /Applications/Firefox.app/Contents/Resources/browser/features/firefox@getpocket.com.xpi
1492032549336   addons.xpi  DEBUG   Calling bootstrap method startup on firefox@getpocket.com version 1.0.5
1492032549342   addons.xpi-utils    DEBUG   Starting async load of XPI database /var/folders/ww/gv287wh16h1dc2_vfkbqhzzsljzc90/T/anonymous2050536623730480419webdriver-profile/extensions.json
1492032549343   addons.xpi  DEBUG   Registering manifest for /Applications/Firefox.app/Contents/Resources/browser/features/webcompat@mozilla.org.xpi
1492032549343   addons.xpi  DEBUG   Loading bootstrap scope from /Applications/Firefox.app/Contents/Resources/browser/features/webcompat@mozilla.org.xpi
1492032549344   addons.xpi  DEBUG   Calling bootstrap method startup on webcompat@mozilla.org version 1.0
1492032549347   addons.manager  DEBUG   Registering shutdown blocker for XPIProvider
1492032549347   addons.manager  DEBUG   Provider finished startup: XPIProvider
1492032549347   addons.manager  DEBUG   Starting provider: LightweightThemeManager
1492032549347   addons.manager  DEBUG   Registering shutdown blocker for LightweightThemeManager
1492032549347   addons.manager  DEBUG   Provider finished startup: LightweightThemeManager
1492032549347   addons.manager  DEBUG   Starting provider: GMPProvider
1492032549355   addons.manager  DEBUG   Registering shutdown blocker for GMPProvider
1492032549356   addons.manager  DEBUG   Provider finished startup: GMPProvider
1492032549356   addons.manager  DEBUG   Starting provider: PluginProvider
1492032549356   addons.manager  DEBUG   Registering shutdown blocker for PluginProvider
1492032549356   addons.manager  DEBUG   Provider finished startup: PluginProvider
1492032549357   addons.manager  DEBUG   Completed startup sequence
1492032549818   addons.xpi-utils    DEBUG   Async JSON file read took 0 MS
1492032549818   addons.xpi-utils    DEBUG   Finished async read of XPI database, parsing...
1492032549822   addons.xpi-utils    DEBUG   Successfully read XPI database
1492032549843   addons.manager  DEBUG   Starting provider: <unnamed-provider>
1492032549843   addons.manager  DEBUG   Registering shutdown blocker for <unnamed-provider>
1492032549844   addons.manager  DEBUG   Provider finished startup: <unnamed-provider>
*** Blocklist::_loadBlocklistFromFile: blocklist is disabled
1492032549976   addons.manager  DEBUG   Starting provider: PreviousExperimentProvider
1492032549976   addons.manager  DEBUG   Registering shutdown blocker for PreviousExperimentProvider
1492032549977   addons.manager  DEBUG   Provider finished startup: PreviousExperimentProvider
2017-04-12 14:29:11.058 plugin-container[31127:15159940] *** CFMessagePort: bootstrap_register(): failed 1100 (0x44c) 'Permission denied', port = 0x933f, name = 'com.apple.tsm.portname'
See /usr/include/servers/bootstrap_defs.h for the error codes.
2017-04-12 14:29:11.060 plugin-container[31127:15159940] *** CFMessagePort: bootstrap_register(): failed 1100 (0x44c) 'Permission denied', port = 0x4f17, name = 'com.apple.CFPasteboardClient'
See /usr/include/servers/bootstrap_defs.h for the error codes.
2017-04-12 14:29:11.060 plugin-container[31127:15159940] void __CFPasteboardSetup() : Failed to allocate communication port for com.apple.CFPasteboardClient; this is likely due to sandbox restrictions

Build info: version: '2.49.1', revision: '808c23b0963853d375cbe54b90bbd052e2528a54', time: '2016-01-21 09:37:52'
System info: host: 'sea-meahm-m1.ds.ad.adp.com', ip: '127.0.0.1', os.name: 'Mac OS X', os.arch: 'x86_64', os.version: '10.11.6', java.version: '1.7.0_79'
Driver info: driver.version: FirefoxDriver

    at org.openqa.selenium.firefox.internal.NewProfileExtensionConnection.start(NewProfileExtensionConnection.java:130)
    at org.openqa.selenium.firefox.FirefoxDriver.startClient(FirefoxDriver.java:246)
    at org.openqa.selenium.remote.RemoteWebDriver.<init>(RemoteWebDriver.java:119)
    at org.openqa.selenium.firefox.FirefoxDriver.<init>(FirefoxDriver.java:191)
    at org.openqa.selenium.firefox.FirefoxDriver.<init>(FirefoxDriver.java:186)
    at org.openqa.selenium.firefox.FirefoxDriver.<init>(FirefoxDriver.java:182)
    at org.openqa.selenium.firefox.FirefoxDriver.<init>(FirefoxDriver.java:99)
    at com.cobaltgroup.websites.kpi.BaseKPILeads$KpiWebDriverFactory.createLocalWebDriver(BaseKPILeads.java:156)
    at com.cobaltgroup.websites.kpi.BaseKPILeads.setup(BaseKPILeads.java:91)
    at com.cobaltgroup.websites.kpi.kia.KiaLeadSubmissionTest.setUp(KiaLeadSubmissionTest.java:57)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:57)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:606)
    at org.junit.runners.model.FrameworkMethod$1.runReflectiveCall(FrameworkMethod.java:47)
    at org.junit.internal.runners.model.ReflectiveCallable.run(ReflectiveCallable.java:12)
    at org.junit.runners.model.FrameworkMethod.invokeExplosively(FrameworkMethod.java:44)
    at org.junit.internal.runners.statements.RunBefores.evaluate(RunBefores.java:24)
    at org.junit.rules.TestWatcher$1.evaluate(TestWatcher.java:55)
    at org.junit.rules.TestWatcher$1.evaluate(TestWatcher.java:55)
    at org.junit.rules.RunRules.evaluate(RunRules.java:20)
    at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner.runLeaf(ParentRunner.java:271)
    at org.junit.runners.BlockJUnit4ClassRunner.runChild(BlockJUnit4ClassRunner.java:70)
    at com.saucelabs.junit.ConcurrentParameterized$SauceClassRunnerForParameters.access$300(ConcurrentParameterized.java:170)
    at com.saucelabs.junit.ConcurrentParameterized$SauceClassRunnerForParameters$2.run(ConcurrentParameterized.java:287)
    at com.saucelabs.junit.ConcurrentParameterized$NonBlockingAsynchronousRunner$1.call(ConcurrentParameterized.java:312)
    at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:262)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1145)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:615)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:745)
```

I found suggestion to downgrade my FF, is there a better solution than that?

Comment: just make sure your geckodriver version supports your ff version. If you have the latest geckodriver you're probably fine

Comment: sn't geckodriver required for Selenium 3.x, I am using Selenium 2.46.0

Comment: That would be your problem then, I'll put a better explanation in an answer :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The ownership of maintaining the **drivers** has been turned to the browsers themselves as there has been work to **add driver support to the w3 standard**.

This means **selenium** is no longer maintaining **drivers**, and you won't be able to use the built in **selenium drivers** in an older **webdriver** version to run the latest **firefox** versions.

Instead, if you want to use the latest browsers reliably, you'll have to download the associated driver, in this case **geckodriver** from **Mozilla**.

This takes a little bit of configuration, and unfortunately there have been a few bumps during this transition of having browsers support the drivers, but things are starting to stabilize and work better.

Your only other alternative is the one you mentioned in your question, you can downgrade the version of **firefox** to the version that **Selenium 2.46.0** supported.

Comment: Thanks @mrfreester. I looked into using geckodriver and it took me some investigation, but finally found something in the internet on how to do this http://seleniumsimplified.com/2016/04/how-to-use-the-firefox-marionette-driver/ helped me in resolving this. Thanks for pointing this lost soul in the right direction :-)